# Adding a reference to a NuGet package adds many unrelated assemblies to output

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard

I'm working on a project, to which I would like to add Prometheus metrics exporting. [There's a pretty great library for it over at NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/prometheus-net) that I've used. The new version (2.0.x, prerelease), however, is supposedly build for .NET Standard. That's fine, but my current project is built for the .NET Framework on Windows. When I add this NuGet package, however, I get over 100 assemblies added to the output of my project, including many that I don't think are related.

I added [an issue for this](https://github.com/prometheus-net/prometheus-net/issues/72) to the project, but the project maintainer came to the conclusion that this is normal. I don't agree, however, and I'd like to know if there is a specific suggestion I can make to improve the situation.

What should prometheus-net change to avoid adding all these assemblies to the output of my project?

Comment: Which version of the framework are you targeting? Have you tried targeting 4.7.1 from your assembly and re-adding the package?

Comment: Have you considered updating your projects csproj file to the newer lighter weight format .net standard and .net core projects default with? You can still target whatever version of .net you want but it makes dependant nuget packages implicit instead of explicit like the old format does.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain is there a way to do that without creating a new .csproj file?

Comment: @Tjaart I'm targeting 4.6.1, does that make a difference?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain moving to the new csproj format didn't change the results; all the same assemblies are copied to the output.

Comment: @Tjaart building for 4.7 didn't make a difference. I don't have the 4.7.1 targeting pack installed.

Comment: If you check this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/10/17/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7-1/ you will see that 4.7.1 adds some stuff for .net standard 2.0, if that is your problem. Not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a flaw/bug/unfortunate side effect of the current .NET Standard 2.0 build situation. When a .NET Framework before 4.7.1 is targeted, the system cannot be sure that all the dependencies exist, so it copies all of these extra assemblies to the output.

4.7.1 has everything that .NET Standard 2.0 needs, so they will not be included if that framework is targeted (though, things might break if an earlier framework is used at runtime).

There is information (and a workaround that seems to work for me) at https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/415#issuecomment-314288712

Comment: So how to support Net462,Net472,NetCore20,NetCore21,NetStandard20 - all these together in one library project. Currently I have built something where I have <TargetFrameworks> with all those define and dependencies added as per condition applied in .csproj file. But while generating VSTS build solution package, it works on NetCore21 but gives System.Runtime v4.2.0.0 error in NetCore20. Something similar with NetFrameworks. Any idea or suggestion on this? Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783149/building-nuget-package-with-nuget-pack-csproj-and-nuget-push-created-package